# 'file owner' in xcode 4.6 issue / metaio configuration

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, metaio

I am new in iPhone programming, I am configuring metaio SDK and within the installation instruction I have to do something with 'file owner' which I've never heard about that as I just studied iOS 5.
could you please how can I do this part in xcode 4.6?

'We will add new UIView element to xib for both iPad and iPhone, and rename the custom class impelemtation for EAGLView. Then link this new GLView to glView Outlet from File's Owner as shown on the image below.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am aware of three ways to connect a view in the Storyboard or Interface builder to the outlet:

1) Use the assistant mode to put the storyboard and the header file side by side. Drag from the small circle on the left side of the @property to the UIView target in the storyboard.

[image: Using assistant mode]

2) Drag from the view controller (or other relevant class that has the outlet) to the  target in the story board, e.g. UIView.

[image: mode 2]

3) Drag from the view controller (or other relevant class that has the outlet) to the correct object, e.g. UIView, in the hierarchy.

[image: Mode 3]

Comment: Thanks for your visual tutorial :)

Answer (score 0):

The File's Owner is the instance of UIViewController class that you are working on.

If you select your XIB file, to the left of the Interface Builder, you should have a hollow looking cube at the top of the little strip, select it. Once you've done that you should see in your Utilities window on the right, as to what class is set as the File's Owner.